# callback na função removeClass jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

Estou tentando usar o `callback` na função `removeClass` mas não esta funcionando, alguém sabe o que esta errado?

Preciso executar o `removeAttr` só depois que terminar o `removeClass`.

```
    $(".context_menu_pai").removeClass('open' , function() {
        $(".context_menu_pai").removeAttr("style");
    });
```

Comment: Estava a responder também mas a pergunta foi apagada, e só agora vi que foi desapagada. Acho que te referes à função iteradora que o método tem. Essa função não é uma callback assíncrona, mas sim para iterar as classes. E nesse caso o método só aceita essa função, como a documentação que o bfavaretto apontou.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Que callback?! [Esse método não aceita callback!](https://api.jquery.com/removeclass/)

Como não há operações assíncronas envolvidas, bastaria encadear as chamadas, assim:

```
$(".context_menu_pai").removeClass('open').removeAttr("style");
```